# Location Hive log with query (Tez)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

Recently I migrated from Hadoop 1.0 to Hadoop 2.0. Now Hive executes on Tez and I cannot find logs with my queries.

I have access to aggregated logs: yarn logs -applicationId application_xxx. But it doesn't contain text of my query

```
"select foo from myTable where day='2015-07-03' "
```

Please help me to find logs with query.

Comment: Look for the location of  <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name> in hive-site.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem!

Following this [instruction](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.0.1.0/bk_ambari_reference_guide/content/_deploying_the_tez_view.html), I created a Tez View in Ambari (Hortonworks). Now I can see a detailed report on each job, and even pictures of the DAG!